# Обеспечить работу js скрипта на сайте с ошибками

Tags: javascript, браузер, обработка-ошибок

Вопрос общего характера.
Есть сайты с разными ошибками в коде (синтаксические ошибки в js, html).
Обычно после ошибок браузер не обрабатывает скрипты, идущие ниже, либо они работают как-то некорректно.

Вопрос: можно ли гарантировано обеспечить работу своего скрипта, подключенного файликом на эту страницу, несмотря на эти ошибки?

Comment: нет, гарантированно - нельзя

Answer (score 1):

Знаю только один способ. Надо чтобы твой скрипт был размещен до остальных скриптов и выполнился до них (то есть в твоем коде не должно быть onload и тому подобных).

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую воспользоваться `Grunt`-ом. С его помощью можно делать минифицированные файлы `JS` и в его же настройках можно включать валидацию `JS` кода.

**Но это не даст Вам 100% гарантии.** Браузеров много, а если учесть особенности `JavaScript`-овых движков в них, то тысячи и того больше.
**Лучше в ручную проверяйте работоспособность в наиболее часто используемых браузерах Ваших клиентов.**

Comment: я могу добиться 100% работы своего скрипта, но я не могу быть уверенным в том, что на сайте, куда люди вставляют скрипт, нет ошибок

Comment: @Skywave Тогда создается впечатление что Вы занимаетесь не **своими проблемами**. Это уже проблемы тех кто использует некорректные скрипты.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от уровня Вашего доступа к системе:

Если полный доступ - пишите грамотно.
Если только к подключению - напишите грамотный загрузчик модулей, загружая все скрипты в `try...catch`, так оставшиеся файлы можно загрузить и запустить без особого влияния вывалившихся скриптов (`JS` очень лоялен к ошибкам, это жуть и дар Богов, в зависимости от взгляда на это).
Если Вы можете только сказать "Вставьте `script#src` и заработает" - Вы решаете чужую проблему, поэтому забейте.

Если же крайне важно чтобы Ваши клиенты получали Ваш **рабочий** продукт - наймите техподдержку, которая будет помогать решать эти проблемы.